# Criando EJBs em projeto Spring MVC - Problemas com Injeção de Dependência

Tags: java, spring-mvc, ejb

Possuo uma aplicação Java com Spring MVC que está dividido em módulos da seguinte forma.

`proj_servicos` = Entidades mapeadas, classes de Repository (comunicação com o banco) e Services (Onde Repository é injetado).

Local onde está o *persistence.xml* para comunicação com o banco.

`proj_web` = Tem o projeto `proj_servicos` como dependência e é responsável por servir as telas do sistema ao usuário.

Meu problema é o seguinte, eu preciso forncecer um EJB quer será executado por batch (Não me culpem, não foi minha escolha, eu só trabalho aqui rs), então criei um projeto `proj_ejb` que possui as interfaces e implementações do EJB e tem o `proj_servicos` como dependência para que seja possível utilizar as mesmas entidades e reaproveitado os métodos de *Repository* e *Service*.

Os Repositories são anotados com `@Resource` e injetados no *Service* com `@Resource` também.
Os Services também são anotados com `@Resource` e injetados no *Controller* com `@Inject`.

Quando tento fazer o mesmo dentro dos EJBs (injetar os *Services* com `@Inject`), ele injeta o `Service` porém o *Repository* que está dentro do *Service* fica `null`, não é injetado.

Já fiz vários testes de substituir os `@Resource` por `@Inject` dentro do *Service* também mas não funcionou. Os EJBs são anotados com `@Remote`.

Alguém sabe o que pode estar acontecendo? Como eu posso resolver essa questão das Injeções de Dependência? Ou estou tentando fazer algo impossível?

Answer (score 0):

Já tentou a anotação @Autowired?
Da uma olhada neste artigo
[http://blog.algaworks.com/injecao-de-dependencias-com-spring](http://blog.algaworks.com/injecao-de-dependencias-com-spring/)